# Nanopb -Decoding failed: zero tag

Tags: protocol-buffers, decode, encode, nanopb

This is my first time writing here so excuse me if i did sometihing wrong.

I need help with "Decoding failed: zero tag" status.

I want to send array using ESP-NOW
Here is my encoding side:

```
epostavke.baterija[0]=razina_baterije[0];
    postavke.baterija[1]=razina_baterije[1];
     postavke.baterija[2]=razina_baterije[2];
      postavke.baterija[03]=razina_baterije[3]; 
      postavke.baterija[4]=razina_baterije[4];
       postavke.baterija[5]=razina_baterije[5];
    pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    pb_encode(&stream, Postavke_fields, &postavke);
    esp_now_send(NULL, (uint8_t *) &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

and after encoding when I print :

```
 Serial.println(postavke.baterija[0]);
   Serial.println(postavke.baterija[1]);
```

it shows me right values - so it means that postavke.baterija[0] has value like postavke.baterija[1] , as example it shows me 87 ,85 it depends.

But problem is when I want to decode it. It shows me :"Decoding failed: zero tag"
Here is code:

```
 enter cod stream = pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
     bool status = pb_decode(&stream, Postavke_fields, &postavke);
        if (!status)
        {
            printf("Decoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
            return ;
        }
     Serial.println("Stigli podaci, a oni glase: ");
     Serial.println(postavke.znak);
   Serial.println(postavke.vrijeme_trajanja);
   Serial.println(postavke.vrijeme_odmora);
   Serial.println(postavke.boja1);
   Serial.println(postavke.boja2);
   Serial.println(postavke.boja3);
   Serial.println(postavke.broj_signala);
   Serial.println(postavke.timer);
   Serial.println(postavke.multicaster);
   Serial.println(postavke.broj_propustenih);
   Serial.println(postavke.random_odmor);
  Serial.println(postavke.baterija[0]);
  Serial.println(postavke.baterija[1]);
```

If i dont use this

`

```
if (!status)

     {
            printf("Decoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
            return ;
        }
```

It decodes everything else but not `"postavke.baterija" array

Here is how I did it in .proto file

```
 message Postavke {
required int32 ID=1;
required int32 znak=2;
required int32 vrijeme_trajanja=3;
required int32 vrijeme_odmora=4;
required int32 boja1=5;
required int32 boja2=6;
required int32 boja3=7;
required int32 broj_signala=8;
required int32 timer=9;
required int32 multicaster=10;
required int32 broj_propustenih=11;
required int32 random_odmor=12;
required int32 svjetlina=13;
 repeated int32  baterija=14 ;
```

}

and here is my .options file

```
Postavke.baterija  max_count:6;
Postavke.baterija  max_size:6;
```

Please help me!!
Where is mistake? Why doenst want to decode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

You need to pass the actual length of your message, instead of the whole length of the buffer.

Now nanopb is reading past the message length, and apparently hitting a zero tag number, which is not valid in Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: `zero bytes can occur in middle of protobuf messages`

Provide the simplest solution

```cpp
size_t size = 0;

for (size = 0; buffer[size] != 0x00 && size < sizeof(buffer); size++)
{
   // You can keep it empty
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, zero bytes can occur in middle of protobuf messages.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I am currently trying to use nanopb and would like to quickly write a demo to get started with nanopb. Therefore, I did not encounter the situation of finding 0x00 in the binary of Protobuf. Once again, thank you for pointing out the relevant errors.